# How to aggregate dates by months or years Mysql

Tags: mysql, sum, aggregate

```
$SQLString = "SELECT    
            count(score) as counts,
            DATE(date),
            SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 1 then 1 ELSE 0 END) Male,
            SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 2 then 1 ELSE 0 END) Female,
            AVG(age) as age, score
            FROM persons  
            WHERE date > '".$_SESSION['date1']."' AND date < '".$_SESSION['date2']."' 
            GROUP BY DATE(date) 
            ORDER BY DATE(date) asc";
```

This is my Query that display some data, like gender,age, etc per day.
How could I aggregate those dates by months or years and display the added data?

Notice me if Im not explain my self as well :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GROUP BY year(date), month(date)`.